# GWT Cell tree, how to use?

Tags: java, gwt, interface, treeview, tree

Can somebody explains how to use the GWT cell tree. I am trying to google it but not finding any valuable tutorial??

Thanks

Comment: The current selected answer is out of date because the links are invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try;

[Google Example 1](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#celltree)

includes onModuleLoad method. :)

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't like the google showcase example like me can use this example; 
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.html

you can just copy paste it and it works.
"

---

Trivial example

---

```
public class CellTreeExample implements EntryPoint {

  /**
   * The model that defines the nodes in the tree.
   */
  private static class CustomTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {

    /**
     * Get the {@link NodeInfo} that provides the children of the specified
     * value.
     */
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
      /*
       * Create some data in a data provider. Use the parent value as a prefix
       * for the next level.
       */
      ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        dataProvider.getList().add(value + "." + String.valueOf(i));
      }

      // Return a node info that pairs the data with a cell.
      return new DefaultNodeInfo<String>(dataProvider, new TextCell());
    }

    /**
     * Check if the specified value represents a leaf node. Leaf nodes cannot be
     * opened.
     */
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
      // The maximum length of a value is ten characters.
      return value.toString().length() > 10;
    }
  }

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a model for the tree.
    TreeViewModel model = new CustomTreeModel();

    /*
     * Create the tree using the model. We specify the default value of the
     * hidden root node as "Item 1".
     */
    CellTree tree = new CellTree(model, "Item 1");

    // Add the tree to the root layout panel.
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(tree);
  }
}
```

"